# What does this mean: print "{0} ({1})"?

Tags: python

what does this mean:

```
print "{0}  ({1})"
```

in this code:

```
for x in [None,3,4.5,"foo",lambda : "moo",object,object()]:
    print "{0}  ({1})".format(x,type(x))
```

Comment: They're placeholders for the call to `string.format(. . .)`. It's the 0th argument, and then the 1st argument in parentheses.

Comment: Current docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: They are [string formatting templates](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: You've misparsed that: it doesn't contain `print "{0}  ({1})"`, but rather `"{0}  ({1})".format(x,type(x))`.

Comment: You should read some python documentation before asking such a fundamental question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, they are placeholders for your string,  here is a bit of an explanation with some examples. Also mentioned, is the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), which explains this very well.

When you provide the arguments for your `format` method, the values of these arguments will be set in these placeholders. The order in which the arguments will be used, depends on how you write these placeholders. You can actually even have empty placeholders "{}", which will just take the arguments in order.

Observe the following examples.

Assuming the following two arguments are set:

```
arg1 = "pretzels"
arg2 = "thirsty"
```

In order placeholders:

```
print("These {0} are making me {1}".format(arg1, arg2))
```

Outputs:

```
These pretzels are making me thirsty
```

Out of order placeholders:

```
print("These {1} are making me {0}".format(arg1, arg2))
```

Outputs:

```
These thirsty are making me pretzels
```

No value provided in placeholders:

```
print("These {} are making me {}".format(arg1, arg2))
```

Output:

```
These pretzels are making me thirsty
```

Comment: If you don't mind, I rearranged some of the grammar in your answer to be a bit more readable. Sorry if I screwed up what you were trying to say ;-)

Comment: @ChristianDean Nope. Not at all. Thanks for doing that.